# Coordinate system along line

Tags: tikz-pgf, grouping, online, coordinates

I would like to draw a coordinate system along some lines in a framework for a structural course. This little coordinate system is called local coordinate system.

At the moment the framework looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article} % say
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,inner sep=0pt,thick,dot/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=4pt}]

\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,4);
\node[dot] (2) at (0,0) [label={[label distance=1mm]270:2}] {};
\node[dot] (3) at (0,2) [label={[label distance=1mm]180:3}] {};
\node[dot] (1) at (0,4) [label={[label distance=1mm]90:1}] {};
\node[dot] (4) at (3,2) [label={[label distance=1mm]0:4}] {};
\node[dot] (5) at (2.5,4) [label={[label distance=1mm]45:5}] {};


\draw   (2) -- (3) node [midway,sloped,below] {3};
\draw   (3) -- (4) node [midway,above,sloped] {4};      
\draw   (2) -- (4) node [midway,above,sloped] {6};      


%\draw [<->] (0,0.8) -- (0,0) -- (0.8,0);
%\draw[->] (-.1,1) -- (-.6,1) node[right] {$y$} coordinate(y axis);
%\draw[->] (-.1,1) -- (-.1,1.5) node {$x$} coordinate(x axis);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of the result of the code above]

And I want something like this:

[image: How I want it to look like]

But I don't know how to do that. Does anyone know that? 
And how do I get some space between the numbers on the lines?

Answer (score 9):

One possibility is to use `markings` decorations. One can also define the mirror case where it goes below the line or can appear with extra options provided by the user but the idea is essentially the same.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,inner sep=0pt,thick,dot/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=4pt},
put coord sys/.style={
decoration={markings,
mark= at position 0.5
with
{
\draw[latex-latex,ultra thin] (2pt,2pt) +(5mm,0) -| +(0,5mm) 
        node[above right,rotate=\pgfdecoratedangle] {$\scriptstyle y$};
\path (2pt+5mm,2pt) 
        node[above right,rotate=\pgfdecoratedangle] {$\scriptstyle x$};

}
},
postaction=decorate}]

\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,4);
\node[dot] (2) at (0,0) [label={[label distance=1mm]270:2}] {};
\node[dot] (3) at (0,2) [label={[label distance=1mm]180:3}] {};
\node[dot] (1) at (0,4) [label={[label distance=1mm]90:1}] {};
\node[dot] (4) at (3,2) [label={[label distance=1mm]0:4}] {};
\node[dot] (5) at (2.5,4) [label={[label distance=1mm]45:5}] {};


\draw[put coord sys]   (2) -- (3);
\draw[put coord sys]   (3) -- (4);      
\draw[put coord sys]   (2) -- (4);      

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be slightly better if the two lines are drawn in one path so that the line join at `(2pt,2pt)` looked better.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, indeed. Fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you soo much! This was exactly what I was looking for! And it worked very well :)

Comment: @ArtWooD My pleasure.

Answer (score 5):

With PSTricks:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{labels=none,ticks=none,arrows=->}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](5,5)
    \rput{30}(2,2){\psaxes(0,0)(-1,-1)(2,2)[$x$,0][$y$,90]}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Explanation:

- `\psset{labels=none,ticks=none,arrows=->}` sets the axes without labels, without ticks but with arrows pointing upward and to the right.
- `\psaxes(0,0)(-1,-1)(2,2)[$x$,0][$y$,90]` draws the axes and the axis names.
- `\rput{30}(2,2){...}` rotates and translates the axes.

### Miscellaneous:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-eucl}
\psset{labels=none,ticks=none,arrows=->,saveNodeCoors}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](5,4)
    \pstGeonode[CurveType=polygon,PointName=none](0,0){A}(5,3){B}(0,3){C}
    \rput{!N-B.y N-B.x atan}(2.3,1.6){\psaxes[linecolor=blue](0,0)(1,1)[$x$,0][$y$,90]}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]